# Get url variable with escape character

Tags: php

How can I get the url variable if it has like an escape character like this '#' ?

example: `www.domain.com/#iname=john&age=23`

I want to get the value of "iname"

Comment: Are you asking how get `john` from that string, or how get that value from the request itself? Everything that is sent after `#` isn't send to the server at all

Comment: i used javascript, problem solved now